# How do you access desktop on Windows 10 with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

I searched everywhere including here http://www.howtogeek.com/198122/32-new-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/ I can't find how I can do this on Windows 10 like on Windows 8.

On Windows 8 when  clicking on Windows keyboard it was working now on Windows 10 you get the menu !

How to do so ?

Comment: in windows 7 win+m and win+d do that, have you tried them?

Comment: With windows 8 I forgot Windows 7 but you're all right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desktop can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. This will minimize all windows and set keyboard focus on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Berend said, there's <kbd>Windows+D</kbd>. But, **another way to do it** is <kbd>Windows+M</kbd>, and then to re-open it you use <kbd>Windows+SHIFT+M</kbd>

Comment: Pressing `Win+D` twice will have the same effect as `Win+M` and `Win+Shift+M`

Comment: @Prasanna you're right, and eating ramen with zoom has the same effect as eating ramen with no zoom. They're just preferences :P

Comment: I did not understand the `eating ramen with zoom` part. I agree that they are just preferences.

Comment: @Prasanna Forget it; my imagination is **waay**  too wide. I meant that some people like ramen with zoom (a sauce) and some don't. :P